# UserInfo.getSessionId() returns NULL for site Guest user

Tags: session, sessionid, userinfo, guest-executable

From a component in my experience site, when  I'm using UserInfo.getSessionId() to get the session id for a guest user, I'm getting NULL value.
For a logged in user it works, but not for guest, any idea why ?

Thanks,
Rohith.

Expecting a valid sessionId for my cometD to establish connection.